# How to create new table from multi nested join statement?

Tags: sql, database, join, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a new table from a multi nested join but keep getting error:

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

This is the join statement:

```
select * 
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
        ON table1.col1 = table2.col1
    FULL OUTER JOIN table3
        ON table3.col1 = table1.col1 
        AND table3.date >= '2017-10-01'
```

This is how I am trying to create the table:

```
select * into newtable from (

select * 
    FROM table1
        LEFT JOIN table2
            ON table1.col1 = table2.col1
        FULL OUTER JOIN table3
            ON table3.col1 = table1.col1 
            AND table3.date >= '2017-10-01'
)
```

what am I doing wrong at the last enclosure?

Comment: You need a table alias after the `)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you mean something like `as x`?

Comment: I would leave out the `as`, but it is optional.

Comment: Now I got this error `The column 'column' was specified multiple times for 'x'.`

The three tables have alot of fields that are common but its in the hundreds

Comment: You need to decide which set of (unique) columns you want in the destination table, instead of just being lazy and using `*`. Surely you don't need three copies of `col1` in the new table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a CTE (Common Table Expression) for it:

```
with
x as (
select * 
    FROM table1
        LEFT JOIN table2
            ON table1.col1 = table2.col1
        FULL OUTER JOIN table3
            ON table3.col1 = table1.col1 
            AND table3.date >= '2017-10-01'
)
select * into newtable from x
```

Comment: tried it without the `x` got this error `An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.`

Comment: tried it with the `x` got error `Incorrect syntax near 'x'`.

Comment: select * into newtable from x

Comment: Just make sure `*` doesn't include any duplicate column names. It looks like at least `col1` will cause a problem.

Comment: this helps error message changed `The column 'abc' was specified multiple times for 'x'.`

all three tables have same name columns but they are in the hundreds of columns. I really just want to stick the result of the select statement regardless of column name into the new table, how can I do this?

Comment: @AaronBertrand how can I avoid this exact problem if each table has hundreds of columns?

Comment: @RustyShackleford You can either use dynamic SQL to build the command and prefix each column with the source table name, or you can manually go through the list of columns and decide which ones you want to keep. Either way, you can't "avoid" this problem using `*`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand is this what you mean by dynamic sql `select ah.*, l.*, u.*, pi.* from ...`

Comment: No, I mean `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N''SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery at all.  Just use `into`:

```
select * 
into newtable
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
        ON table1.col1 = table2.col1
    FULL OUTER JOIN table3
        ON table3.col1 = table1.col1 
        AND table3.date >= '2017-10-01';
```

Of course, `select *` won't really work, because your column names need to be unique.  But I'm guessing you are listing them out in your real query.

Also, filtering tables in a `full outer join` is tricky.  I usually recommend a subquery for that purpose.

Comment: how would you handle the outer join in your query? new to this, but only want records from 2017-10-01 onward?

Comment: @RustyShackleford . . . You probably just want a `left join`.

Comment: that helps, how ever in these three tables many of the columns are the same, I am being told I need to list them out, so thinking of way i can get around that. THere are hundreds of columns in each.